# Gridview loop each row go give different data in datasource of fropdownlist

Tags: gridview, loops, datasource, row

I have a gridview with one column of dropdownlist. In this dropdownlist, different row will show different data. because through this dropdownlist, we can choose a manager for this employee (the current row), so it shouldn't contrain the name of this employee.

My problem is all the dropdownlists are showing the list only without the last row's employee instead of the current row employee.

My codebehind is like this:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GVListeSalarie.Rows
            Dim s_id As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("SalarieID"), TextBox)
            Dim strSql As String = "select * from p_salarie where sal_id <>" & s_id.Text
            dsmanager.SelectCommand = strSql
Next
```

Does anyone know why it shows only the result of the last time loop? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I moved my sqldatasource into the gridview, thus I can make the dropdownlist in each line has its own datasource.
And the codebehind is like this:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GVListeSalarie.Rows
            Dim s_id As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("SalarieID"), TextBox)
            Dim strSql As String = "select * from p_salarie where sal_id <>" & s_id.Text
            Dim dsrow As SqlDataSource = CType(row.FindControl("dsmanager"), SqlDataSource)
            dsrow.SelectCommand = strSql

        Next
```